# $U_1,U_2,...$ i.i.d. $U[0,1]$, $P\sim \mathrm{Poi}(\lambda)$, find $F_{\operatorname{min}(U_1,...,U_P)}$

Tags: probability, random-variables, uniform-distribution, poisson-distribution

> Let $(U_n)_n$ a sequence of random variables i.i.d $U[0,1]$ and let $P\sim \mathrm{Poi}(\lambda)$ a random variable such that $P$ is independent of $(U_n)_n$. Let
>   $$
> \\ X=\left\{\begin{matrix}
> \operatorname{min}\{U_1,...,U_P\},    P\ne 0\\ 
> 1,P=0
> \end{matrix}\right.
> $$
>   Find $F_X(t)$.

I saw that the solution is 
$$
\ F_X(t)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
0,t\leq 0\\ 
1-e^{-\lambda t},0\leq t<1 \\
1, 1\leq t
\end{matrix}\right.\\
$$
But my solution is $F_X(t)=e^{-\lambda}(e^{\lambda t}-1)$ and I don't know where is my mistake:

Obviously for $1\leq t$ then $\mathbb{P}(X\leq t)=1$ and if $t<0$ then $\mathbb{P}(X\leq t)=0$. For $0\leq t <1$,
$$
\\ \mathbb{P}(X\leq t)=\mathbb{P}(X\leq t,P=0)+\mathbb{P}(X\leq t,P>0)  \
$$
But if $P=0$ then $X=1$ then $\mathbb{P}(X\leq t,P=0)=0$, thus
$$
\\   \mathbb{P}(X\leq t)=\mathbb{P}(X\leq t, P>0)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\prod_{j=1}^k\mathbb{P}(U_j\leq t)\right)\mathbb{P}(P=k)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty {(t\lambda)^k\over k!}\cdot e^{-\lambda}   \
\\ =e^{-\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^\infty{(t\lambda)^k\over k!}-e^{-\lambda}=    e^{-\lambda}\cdot e^{t\lambda} -e^{-\lambda} =e^{-\lambda}(e^{\lambda t}-1).\
$$

Comment: You seme to assume that $P=k$ implies $\min (U_1,U_2,...,U_P)=U_k$ which is false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $P(0\le X\le 1)=1$, it suffices to show that
$$
\Bbb P(X>t)=e^{-\lambda t}
$$ for all $t\in [0,1)$. Note that
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\Bbb P(X>t)&=&\sum_{k=0}^\infty \Bbb P(X>t, P=k)\\
&=&\sum_{k=0}^\infty \Bbb P(\min\{U_1,\ldots,U_k\}>t, P=k)\\
&=&\sum_{k=0}^\infty \Bbb P(\min\{U_1,\ldots,U_k\}>t)\Bbb P( P=k)\\
&=&\sum_{k=0}^\infty \Bbb P(U_i>t,\forall i\le k)\Bbb P( P=k)\\
&=&\sum_{k=0}^\infty  (1-t)^k\Bbb P( P=k)\\
&=&\sum_{k=0}^\infty  (1-t)^k\frac{\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}}{k!}\\
&=&\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(\lambda(1-t))^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}=e^{\lambda(1-t)}e^{-\lambda}=e^{-\lambda t}
\end{eqnarray}$$ as desired.